# Restrict each user to a single Assets folder

Tags: assets

I need every control panel user to have a single assets folder that is private to them. Is there any way of achieving this in Craft?

I've tried using the "Restrict uploads to a single folder?" option and then used the {author.username} for the subfolder. This works as expected for uploading inside an entry form (although the entry must be saved before existing files can be added to the field, which isn't a great experience), but in the Assets area of the control panel, where users would need to go to be able to delete/manage their assets, the user then has access to ever other user's subfolder.

If anyone has any ideas for how I can achieve what I need, I'd greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE:

I found a plugin called Asset Subfolder Access (By P&T) which allows me to achieve what I want. Although, it's based on User Groups so I'll have to make a group for every user, which isn't ideal. I've also found that the "restrict to single folder" option on Asset fields doesn't allow the user to access subfolders of that location, which isn't great.